# Sharing necessary application data between developers in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

CakePHP has a process (schema shell and files) for sharing database structure between developers. However, there is often need to share some data (e.g. default user groups) as well. How have you solved this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use fixtures for this.  fixtures are small sets of data that can be used for testing or developing purposes. There is an interesting article about this here:

http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/tag/cake-fixtures/

There are also plugins which help with the whole db migration process though I didn't try them out yet you might find them interesting:

http://cakedc.com/pierre_martin/2010/02/05/cakephp-migrations-plugin-easily-version-and-deploy-whole-applications

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Too bad there is no fixtures shell in default CakePHP distribution, and the debuggable.com fixtures shell seems long abandoned.